# Determining $b$ is a linear combination of $a_1,a_2,$ and $a_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So, I put this in an augmented matrix and reduced it. I am confused as to what I need to do from here?

Determine if $b$ is a linear combination of $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$, the columns of the matrix $A$, where $A$ and $b$ are given by
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
4&-8&-8\\
-3&-7&-8\\
5&11&7
}, \quad
b = \pmatrix{
-16\\-15\\13
}
$$

I found the solutions to be $2, -1, 2$

Comment: I am trying to determine that if there is indeed a solution, then it CAN be written as a linear combination. Can anyone verify?

Comment: Actually, it MUST be written as a linear combination. If $\vec{x}$ is the solution, then $b=\vec{x}\cdot A$.

Comment: So because it is a solution to the matrix, it is a linear combination? Given the formula Ax=b

Comment: @frabala $\vec x \cdot A$ (assuming $\cdot$ is matrix multiplication and $x$ is a row vector) yields a linear combination of the **rows, not the columns**, unless you're using some other form of [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29)

Comment: @KnowledgeGeek not exactly.  Because $Ax = b$ *has a solution*, $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Sorry, I meant $b=A\vec{x}$ and I assumed it is a column vector.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x$ is a column vector given by $x = \pmatrix{x_1&x_2&x_3}^T$ ("${}^T$" here means transpose), then 
$$
Ax = x_1a_1 + x_2a_2 + x_3a_3
$$
So, what we're really asking then is whether there is a column vector $x$ for which
$$
Ax = b
$$
In order to find this $x$, we solve the system of equations given by $Ax = b$ using row-reduction, that is, by row-reducing the augmented matrix $\pmatrix{A&b}$.

Row reducing yields the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{10}{73} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{73} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{138}{73} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
From which we deduce that $x = \frac{1}{73}\pmatrix{-10&3&138}^T$ is the unique solution to this problem.